# Group by on a complex object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, sorting

I've an array that contains assignments of employees on tasks, it looks like something like this:

```
$scope.assignments = [
    { 
      employee: {
        id:"1", firstname:"John", lastname:"Rambo"
      },
      task: {
        name:"Kill everyone", project:"Destruction"
      },
      date: {
        day:"01/01", year:"1985"
      }
    },
    {
      employee: {
        id:"2", firstname:"Luke", lastname:"Skywalker"
      },
      task: {
        name:"Find daddy", project:"Star Wars"
      },
      date: {
        day:"65/45", year:"1000000"
      }        
    },
    {
      employee: {
        id:"1", firstname:"John", lastname:"Rambo"
      },
      task: {
        name:"Save the world", project:"Destruction"
      },
      date: {
        day:"02/01", year:"1985"
      }
    }
];
```

I would like to group by employee, for having something like this:

```
$scope.assignmentsByEmployee = [
    { //First item
      id:"1", 
      firstname:"John",
      lastname:"Rambo",
      missions: [
        {
          name:"Kill everyone",
          date:"01/01",
          year:"1985"
        },
        {
          name:"Save the world",
          date:"02/01",
          year:"1985"
        }
      ]
    },
    { //Second item
      id="2",
      firstname:"Luke",
      lastname:"Skywalker",
      missions: [
        name:"Find daddy",
          date:"65/45",
          year:"1000000"         
      ]
   }
];
```

Is their a simple way to do this ? I tried something with a double `forEach`, but it leads me nowhere.

Hope I'm understandable :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to loop through the assignments array and create a 'keyed array' (which just means using an object in JavaScript) on employee ID. Then you just fill up the missions array as required.

Something like

```
// initialise a holding object
var assignmentsByEmployee = {};

// loop through all assignemnts
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.assignments.length; i++) {
    // grab current assignment
    var currentAssignment = $scope.assignments[i];
    // grab current id
    var currentId = currentAssignment.employee.id;

    // check if we have seen this employee before
    if(assignmentsByEmployee[currentId] === undefined) {
        // we haven't, so add a new object to the array
        assignmentsByEmployee[currentId] = {
            id: currentId,
            firstname: currentAssignment.employee.firstname,
            lastname: currentAssignment.employee.lastname,
            missions: []
        };
    }

    // we know the employee exists at this point, so simply add the mission details
    assignmentsByEmployee[currentId].missions.push({
        name: currentAssignment.task.name,
        date: currentAssignment.date.day,
        year: currentAssignment.date.year
    });
}
```

These leaves `assignmentsByEmployee` as an object, but you can simply foreach through it and convert it back to an array if required. E.g:

```
$scope.assignmentsByEmployee = [];
for(var employeeId in assignmentsByEmployee) {
    $scope.assignmentsByEmployee.push(assignmentsByEmployee[employeeId]);
}
```